# Would my display be usable after removing touch screen glass?

Tags: display, touchscreen, laptop-display, digitizer

I have a zenbook pro ux501vw and find the display unusably reflective at times. I also don't use the touchscreen at all, so it occurred to me that it might be possible to simply remove the glass, sacrificing the touch functionality for a less reflective experience. I was thinking of either removing the full glass assembly or simply using a glass cutter to just cut the outline of the lcd, leaving the bezel. Obviously I want to make sure that the screen is still usable visually afterwards; for example, I recall that older LCD displays had a polarizer on the surface closest to the user that if removed left you with a blank white screen, so I'd obviously want to avoid that sort of scenario. Any thoughts on whether this mod is likely to disable the visual functionality of the screen?

Comment: So you want to remove the glass because of the glare?  That just sounds like an extremely dangerous idea.  There are heavy metals in some screens.  Not to mention the potential for jagged edges if you cut it.  There is anti-glare film you can put on a screen that is not terribly expensive.

Answer (score 0):

This will most assuredly result in permanently damaging the screen. If you manage to remove the glass, the exposed screen will be very vulnerable, and will probably be at least as glossy.

In short, this is a horrible idea and please don't do it.

I recommended getting a matte screen protector instead, as that will solve your problem without damaging your device.